# Can a Slayer use Studied Target outside combat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, non-combat

Is it possible for a Slayer to study a Target outside of battle to gain the bonuses for roleplaying purposes, rather than combat bonuses?

Answer (score 5):

### Yes, you can

Activating [Studied Target](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/hybrid-classes/SLAYER/#TOC-Studied-Target-Ex-) is a *move action*, and there is nothing in the ability that restricts its use to combat situations. All actions are also possible out of combat (otherwise we couldn't even move around). As such, a slayer is allowed to walk around the city and declare that he is studying a guard, a merchant or any bystander, in order to benefit from the skill bonuses from *Studied Target*.

Comment: It should be noted there might well be consequences for taking such combat-oriented actions, even outside of combat. The targets might well take it as a signal to begin combat, if the slayer is observed doing so.

Comment: @YogoZuno this particular one is nothing more than looking at someone for few seconds.

Comment: And? Most combat actions involve doing something noticeable for a few seconds. If someone draws a blade (also a move action), should you not get a chance to roll initiative?